# Azure Data Factory - copy data from PostgreSQL on VM

Tags: postgresql, azure, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pull data from Postgresql on Azure using Azure Data Factory but have no luck. Both ADF and VM are in the same Azure Vnet.
In my VM networking settings I allowed port 5432 inbound access from ADF to VirtualNetwork. Similar outbound vnet to vnet.
I also installed ODBC driver on VM and added it to firewall.
I installed also the selfhosted integration runtime on VM which connects to ADF.
When creating a new Linked Service on ADF I chose PostgreSQL as source.
Not able to establish connection though.
Tried different settings:
-IP and DNS as servername
-self hosted and auto resolve integration runtime
-public and private IP
-no encryption and encryption
-temporarily turned off firewall on vm to test
still no success.
What am I missing?
password and database names are correct.

The error message I am getting when testing connection:
Error code
9603
Details
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number.
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Can't connect to server on 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx'

I would appreciate it if anyone could help.
Thank you

Comment: From your VM, are you able to ping and telnet to your Azure postgresql Server?

Comment: the postgresql database is on the same Azure vm. I is not the Azure postgresql database as a service

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I need to use the ODBC connector as a linked service on ADF, not the PostgreSQL connector. Bingo!